# Create a Button that opens a VF page as a subtab in console

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, subtab-apps

How would you do this as apparently, the srcUp method doesn't work for Visualforce pages

Answer (score 2):

You need to use javascript and the [Service Console Integration Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/index.htm).
Specifically, you will need to use the `openSubtab` method.

Here is a sample of what it looks like:

```
<A HREF="#" onClick="testOpenSubtab();return false">
    Click here to open a new subtab</A> 

<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/22.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testOpenSubtab() {
        //First find the ID of the primary tab to put the new subtab in
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    }

    var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
        //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can open a new subtab in it
        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'http://www.salesforce.com', false, 
            'salesforce', null, openSuccess, 'salesforceSubtab');
    };

    var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether we succeeded in opening the subtab
        if (result.success == true) {
            alert('subtab successfully opened');
        } else {
            alert('subtab cannot be opened');
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How can I test it in a developer org?

Comment: Make sure your test user has the "Service Cloud User" checked on the user record. Then use a console app, or create one.